# Python: How to create a list of lists, with paired by twos subsequent numbers

Tags: python, list, for-loop, cycle, digits

Apologies if my thread title doesn't properly describe the number.

I have this list:

```
statements_order = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [6,7], [8,9], [10,11], [12,13], [14,15], [16,17], [18,19]]
```

I want to know how I can program this in one line using Python. I've tried the following, but of course, it's invalid syntax after the first ')'.

```
testOrder = [[x for x in range(0,20,2), y for y in range(1,21,2)] for z in range(20)]
```

I feel like I'm not using the correct approach, so please help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want:

```
[[x,x+1] for x in range(0,19,2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use 2 fors in you list comprehension. Only one is enough:

```py
[[i,i+1] for i in range(0,20,2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with append method. You may probably already know this, but Just in case.

```
c=[]
for i in range(0,20,2):
    v=[i,i+1]
    c.append(v)
print(c)
```